# How to gently ask when I will receive my pay?

Tags: salary

I'm currently doing an internship to validate my second year post bac (I'm living in France).

And this week announced the 7th week of 10 of this one. That's not my 1st intention and that's always nice to get it but... I still have no hearing of this pay.

As a joke and as quick as lightning he said me (I don't really remember the context, it was like I was asking "How..." and he replied: ) "How I will pay you? I don't know" with a laugh.

**My question:** How could I ask when will it intends to pay me but so professionally and non offensive manner?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Do you have information from when you started on what the pay would be and when the pay periods are?  Are there requirements for how often someone should be paid in your location, and do they apply to internships?  Do you have a contract?

Comment: I've stater the 4th of April (and i'm ending the 10th of June). For how often, it should be around 500 euros /month. And yes, I have a contract but that's not mentioned. Or did I looked wrong? I'll have a look.

Comment: Does the company have a dedicated HR? Maybe you should talk to them, and hopefully they won't brush off your question with a joke.

Comment: Don't be afraid to offend if that is what it takes. This is not a joke! Unless you or your family are independently wealthy, getting paid is a very serious matter! Do I need to explain to you what happens when you don't have enough money to pay your rent? Or pay your water or your electricity? Or pay for food? Or pay for the bus to go to work? Don't be ashamed to admit that you've planned for that money and that you need it. This is just a fact. There is nothing to be embarrassed about. I was also born in France and I realize that French people have weird feelings about asking for money.

Comment: I understand your point of view and you are absolutely right!

Comment: Imagine the tone and body language your boss would use if you decided to come in late every day and do no work, and ask for your pay like that

Answer (score 9):

Here are the steps you should go through:

- Your offer letter, or one of the other documents you received when you accepted this position, should have told you when you would be paid. Read these, and find out if you should have been paid by now. Different companies pay on different schedules, but not being paid for seven weeks is extremely unusual and probably wrong.
- If for some reason those documents don't tell you that, you need to ask for that information. HR is probably the best place to go to find it out.
- Don't ask about a serious subject in a joking way. Asking in a joking way will get you a joking answer. Asking in a serious way is not offensive or unprofessional, and should get you a serious answer.
- If you should have been paid by now, you need to find out why you haven't been. HR is most likely to be helpful, so ask them, but you should also tell your boss about this problem. Do this quickly and, again, in a non-joking way. This is a serious matter.
- There are a number of reasons why you might not have been paid, including the possibility that they are waiting for you to give them some information, or that they have your bank details wrong. If it's this kind of problem (or just a mistake on their part) HR should be able to sort this out quickly.
- If it turns out that this is not a mistake, and they don't intend to do something about it, you need to take action. In every country I have worked in, and almost certainly in France, there are laws about when a company has to pay its workers, and not paying them for seven weeks is almost certainly illegal. Make a written complaint and follow up on it.
- If this was set up as part of your education, get in touch with your school or college and let them know what is happening.

Comment: This pretty much covers it, I would make a point of asking in righting so that there is a paper trail from start to end

Comment: Also, don't be embarassed about it or feel it's unprofessional to ask. 'When should I expect my first paycheck?" is commonly asked by anyone who has just started a job, whatever their age or years of experience.

Answer (score 0):

**Internship**
Here in the Netherlands we usually don't get pay for an internship unless you are doing it on a college level. At school they told us never to expect to be paid because you are there to learn.
Seeing as you have been offered a paid internship, read your contract and anything else you have signed and make sure it has been written there. That being said if it isn't written down this could mean they will pay you in one go at the end of your time there (have seen it before).

> **Note**
>   I had a paid internship and it was written in my "school to internship contract" and my work contract.

**Solution**
Seeing as they said they would pay you, just ask about it. Just ask your boss if he has sometime to discuss a matter and ask him about it if you want to do it privately.
Or as some of the comments stated take it up with HR. Just keep in mind that if you haven't found where it has been written down in a contract you might be $#!+ out of luck!

Comment: In France, beyond a certain duration, it's mandatory. And here, it's my case with 10 weeks. So I'll ask him. Thanks.

Comment: In france, whe doing an intership for more than 8 weeks, you have to be paid according to the law. Company have reduced taxes for doing interships.

Comment: Ah! Didn't know that, sounds like a good law. Thanks :)

Comment: @kiwi not really true, you get payed if you either are in a specific section or recorded it in the Terms of your contract